# Is it correct to say "index and thumb" without the word "fingers"?

Tags: word-usage

Example sentence:

> Takahashi caressed my middle finger with her index and thumb.

I see both instances on [Google](https://encrypted.google.com/search?ei=uxJfWuXVCsah8QW8tZ2ABA&q=%22her%20index%20and%20thumb%22&oq=%22her%20index%20and%20thumb%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...3056.4125.0.4293.2.2.0.0.0.0.82.123.2.2.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.1.81...33i22i29i30k1.0.w4NamKD3iYQ).

Answer (score 1):

The word Index means many things and so it is one of those words where context is imperative.

Though not grammatically correct, the meaning is quite clear as the action of caressing a finger was induced by an index (finger) and a thumb. The context in which the word is used is evident. The finger was not caressed by a catalogue, now was it?

Nevertheless, given the context in which this sentence resides, it could add to a feeling of suspense. The writer may be using short sentences in the passage to build upon something. Who knows...

Comment: What's the grammatical mistake?